# How can I add/merge values from one existing column to another column - Python - Pandas - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas

Good Morning,

This is my code

```py
data = {'Names_Males_GroupA': ['Robert', 'Andrew', 'Gordon', 'Steve'], 'Names_Females_GroupA': ['Brenda', 'Sandra', 'Karen', 'Megan'], 'Name_Males_GroupA': ['David', 'Patricio', 'Noe', 'Daniel']}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

[image]

Since  **Name_Males_GroupA** has an error (*missing and 's'*)
I need to move all the values to the correct column which is  **Names_Males_GroupA**

In other words: I want to Add the names David, Patricio, Noe and Daniel below the names Robert, Andrew, Gordon and Steve.

After that I can delete the wrong column.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a connection between the Male and the Female in a row? It seems like you just want to hold two separate lists of male and female group members. For that pandas Series would be more suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can try

```py
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :2], df.iloc[:, 2].to_frame('Names_Males_GroupA')], ignore_index=True)
```

```
print(df)

  Names_Males_GroupA Names_Females_GroupA
0             Robert               Brenda
1             Andrew               Sandra
2             Gordon                Karen
3              Steve                Megan
4              David                  NaN
5           Patricio                  NaN
6                Noe                  NaN
7             Daniel                  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break them apart and put them back together with a pd.concat

```
data = {'Names_Males_GroupA': ['Robert', 'Andrew', 'Gordon', 'Steve'], 'Names_Females_GroupA': ['Brenda', 'Sandra', 'Karen', 'Megan'], 'Name_Males_GroupA': ['David', 'Patricio', 'Noe', 'Daniel']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df[['Name_Males_GroupA', 'Names_Females_GroupA']]
df1.columns = ['Names_Males_GroupA', 'Names_Females_GroupA']
df = df[['Names_Males_GroupA', 'Names_Females_GroupA']]
pd.concat([df, df1])
```